# Catching details of exception in Python

Tags: python, macos-catalina

I am running Python 3.7 on macOS 10.15 Catalina and ever since I upgraded, I get several problematic exceptions when my code runs that never occurred before:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Couldn't close file
```

I do not really understand why there is a problem all of a sudden (and what's the cause), but I want to find the exact line in my code where this exception is thrown. How can I obtain e.g. the line number in the code where this exception occurs?

Comment: could you, please, post a code snippet where exception happens?

Comment: @ymochurad Unfortunately, I can't because I do not know where this exception occurs. :/ At the moment the problem is not even reproducible for me (it occurs, however, every time I run my code at some point, though not at the exact same times).

Comment: You might have noticed it is a C++ exception, not a Python one.

Comment: Indeed @OneLyner That is also the cause of my troubles because I do not know how to get details on that exception...

Comment: At least, you're not alone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15410

Comment: Intersting! Thanks for the hint @OneLyner 

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something similar today when running python script for an LDA model using the Gensim package in Jupyter Lab.

I entered the print statements to see if there is anything wrong with the for loop code, which works fine outside a loop.

Jupyter Lab Input:

```
limit = 30
start=2
step=2

coherence_values = []

for num_topics in range(start, limit, step):
    lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                       id2word=id2word,
                                       num_topics=num_topics,
                                       random_state=100,
                                       update_every=1,
                                       chunksize=len(corpus),
                                       passes=10,
                                       alpha='auto',
                                       per_word_topics=True)
    print(f'LDA model {num_topics} created')
    coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=data_lemmatized, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')
    print(f'Coherence model {num_topics} created')
    coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
    print(f'Coherence value {num_topics} obtained')
    coherence_values.append(coherence_lda)
```

Jupyter Lab Output:

```
LDA model 2 created
Coherence model 2 created
Coherence value 2 obtained
LDA model 4 created
Coherence model 4 created
Coherence value 4 obtained
LDA model 6 created
Coherence model 6 created
```

No python errors occur -- the code cell simply keeps running without error, but in my terminal I observe 11 counts of the following error.

Terminal error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
std::runtime_error: Couldn't close file
```

It seems the code runs fine, and that the error occurs after 3 of the 14 loops are run. Sometimes one loop runs, sometimes two.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to set parameter `processes` of class `CoherenceModel` to a specific num (maybe 1 for safe). The source code of CoherenceModel about `processes` is like below, you can see by default the caculation is carried out with multiprocesses, the num of processes is decided by the num of cpus:

```
"""     
processes : int, optional
       Number of processes to use for probability estimation phase, any value less than 1 will be interpreted as num_cpus - 1.
"""
 self.processes = processes if processes >= 1 else max(1, mp.cpu_count() - 1)
```

I use macOS Monterey and python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue too since upgrading to macOS Catalina (same error thrown); and unfortunately for me, the only sensible and reliable solution as I see it now is to rewrite the code to avoid using `multiprocessing` at all, then the issue goes away. So any thing having to do with multiprocessing in `Python 3.7` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) has to go...

Comment: I have since then resolved all the issues by moving from multiprocessing to joblib (https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Hope this helps!